# pipe a program into less

Tags: bash, stdout, pipe, stderr, less

I'm taking the dive into setting up and learning git and at the same time learning bash. I'm trying to do something simple as view the help section of

```sh
$ git config
```

unfortunately, when I type that the output of the help goes off the screen. Doing some googling I found less to be the program I want to use to scroll.

I tried

```sh
$ git config | less
```

with no success. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Git is probably writing its output into standard error stream instead of standard output stream because command parameters are not correct. Please read about Unix standard streams [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams).

To fix the problem you have to [redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) the error stream into output stream like this:

`git config 2>&1 | less`

Answer (score 5):

Piping only redirects stdout. If you want stderr as well then you need to redirect that to stdout first.

```
git config 2>&1 | less
```